# c# regex, text between tags

Tags: c#, regex

I'm having something like that:

```
{
   Regex regex = new Regex(@"expression here");
   foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(textBoxResponse.Text))
      {
      MessageBox.Show(match.Value.ToString());
      }
}
```

What expression should I use to get only EXAMPLE from this response?

```
<a href="spieler.php?uid=xxx">EXAMPLE</a>
```

Comment: `"EXAMPLE"` should work :)

Comment: Do not use regex to parse HTML/XML text. See here for one of the most famous questions on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Forgot to add that I'm having lots of lines with different text which I named EXAMPLE :P

Answer (score 3):

Consider using the [htmlagilitypack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) for this.

Edit:

Updated the example based on Casimir et Hippolyte's suggestion
A quick introduction to XPATH can be read here: http://zvon.org/xxl/XPathTutorial/General/examples.html

<s>The following code finds all the hyperlinks on a page. Reference:http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples</s>

```
var doc = new HtmlDocument(); //HtmlDocument class is part of the htmlagilitypack
doc.LoadHtml(@"<html><body><a href='spieler.php?uid=xxx'>EXAMPLE</a></body></html>");

foreach(var linkText in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a/text()"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(linkText.InnerText);
}
```

Comment: Why not using `//a/text()` as xpath query?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: that is indeed the better way. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

this should work, it will look at text between > and < / a>

```
 (?<=>)(.*?)(?=</a>)
```

but as stated in the comments i would not advise to parse html with regex

Comment: @user3014282 you should be doing something like `Regex regex = new Regex("(?<=>)(.*?)(?=</a>)");
            string e = "<a href=\"spieler.php?uid=xxx\">EXAMPLE</a>";
            string result = regex.Split(e)[1];`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following Regex...

```
(?<=\>).*?(?=<)
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
var html = @"<a href=""spieler.php?uid=xxx"">EXAMPLE</a>";
var matches = Regex.Matches(html, @"<a\ href=""spieler\.php\?uid=[^""]*"">([^(</a>)]*)</a>");
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

Hope that helps :)
Or if you wish to use Linq.

```
var html = @"<a href=""spieler.php?uid=xxx"">EXAMPLE</a>";
var matches = Regex.Matches(html, @"<a\ href=""spieler\.php\?uid=[^""]*"">([^(</a>)]*)</a>");
var examples = (from Match match in matches select match.Groups[1].Value).ToList();
```